# How to achieve a gaussian blur with React Native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, blur, gaussian

I know there are some packages that let you create a blur view, but they all have sharp edges. There is also a blurRadius prop for the Image component, but it also renders an image with sharp edges.

How can I achieve a blurred image without sharp edges?
So I can achieve an effect like: https://www.invisionapp.com/blog/ios-10-style-shadows-sketch/